# Get coordinates of border crossing in a route

Tags: openstreetmap

Let's say I'm using OSRM to route through 3 countries. What would be the best way to get coordinates of where, in the route, borders will be corssed?

Thanks.

Comment: Minimal example (http://osrm.at/fhH), in the instructions currently there isn't a related message to use. You can try crossing the route information with the borders themselves

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to mark the nodes as border nodes while you import the data. Then it should be trivial to get the border information while returning the route.

Answer (score 0):

In my database (not using OSRM...) every node is assigned to a region. (That could also be an administrative boundary.)